# What is scala's version of ArrayList and Tuple?

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to convert the following code segment

```
public org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector call(Tuple2<IntWritable, VectorWritable> arg0)
                        throws Exception {

                    org.apache.mahout.math.Vector mahoutVector = arg0._2.get();
                    Iterator<Element> elements = mahoutVector.nonZeroes().iterator();
                    ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> tupleList = new ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>();
                    while (elements.hasNext()) {
                        Element e = elements.next();
                        if (e.index() >= nCols || e.get() == 0)
                            continue;
                        Tuple2<Integer, Double> tuple = new Tuple2<Integer, Double>(e.index(), e.get());
                        tupleList.add(tuple);
                    }
                    org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector sparkVector = Vectors.sparse(nCols, tupleList);
                    return sparkVector;
                }
```

I am fairly new to scala so I dont know how to properly convert it. So far I got

```
def transformSvec(x: Vector) : org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = {
    val iter=x.nonZeroes.iterator()    
    //iterate the items and add to an arraylist
    //or an iterable/seq for scala, if var seq: Seq[(Int, scala.Double)] is chosen then
    org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.sparse(x.size, seq)
}
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuple comes from Scala, not Java.  In Scala you can use the proper syntax though `(IntWritable, VectorWriteable)` is special syntax for the type `Tuple2[IntWriteable, VectorWriteable]`

You can also instantiate your tuples using this syntax. Your java code

```
 Tuple2<Integer, Double> tuple = new Tuple2<Integer, Double>(e.index(), e.get());
```

Becomes

```
val tuple = (e.index(), e.get())
```

You can use ArrayList from Scala if you like, nothing will stop you, but it's generally prefered to use the Scala collections as they have more features an work better with the rest of Scala.  `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer` is the Scala equivalent to `java.util.ArrayList`.

However, it's not common in Scala to add things to a collection in a loop like you would in Java.  Usually you would use immutable collections and methods like `map`, `flatmap`, and `filter` to transform and generate new collections.  In your case you can use

```
val tupleList = x.nonZeroes.iterator()
  .filter(e => e.index < ncols)
  .filter(e => e.get != 0)
  .map(e => (e.index(), e.get))
  .toSeq
```

To generate your sequence.

Comment: It is throwing the following error: "value filter is not a member of java.util.Iterator[org.apache.mahout.math.Vector.Element]"

Comment: @user3086871 if you have a java iterator you need to convert it to a Scala iterator first, `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` with that import you can call `.asScala` in the iterator to convert it into a Scala iterator.

Answer (score 1):

In Mahout 0.13.0 you can also use `MahoutCollections`

```
import org.apache.mahout.math.scalabindings.MahoutCollections._

val a = Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
val v: Vector = new org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector(a)

v.toArray
```

You can pass an array to the constructor of a Spark Vector

Comment: This would be the preferred method for using Mahout.